# ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE has missing FROM-clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple table (id and name column, both unique), which I am importing a tab delimited CSV file.

I am running psql 9.5, and wanted to try out the new `ON CONFLICT` feature to update the name column if the ID already exists.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM repos LIMIT 0;
COPY tmp_x FROM '/Users/George/git-parser/repo_file' (format csv, delimiter E'\t');
INSERT INTO repos SELECT * FROM tmp_x
ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET name = tmp_x.name;
DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```

I am getting this error:

```
SELECT 0
COPY 1
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tmp_x"
LINE 4: ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET name = tmp_x.name;
                                               ^
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: missing FROM-clause entry for table "tmp_x"
```

Not too sure whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation of the `ON CONFLICT` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), it says this about the "conflict action":

> The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias)

In your query, the target table is `repos`.

`tmp_x`, on the other hand, is the source of the data you are trying to insert, but the `ON CONFLICT` clause cannot "see" that - it is looking at a particular row that has been calculated and failed. Consider if you'd written something like this:

```
INSERT INTO repos SELECT max(foo_id) FROM tmp_x
```

Clearly, it wouldn't make sense for a row which failed to insert into `repos` to have access to any one row from `tmp_x`.

If there was no way of seeing the rejected data, the whole feature would be pretty useless, but if we read on:

> ... and to rows proposed for insertion using the special excluded table.

So instead, you need to access the magic table alias `excluded`, which contains the values which you tried to insert but got a conflict on, giving you this:

```
INSERT INTO repos SELECT * FROM tmp_x
ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET name = excluded.name;
```

If it seems weird that an imaginary table name pops up for this purpose, consider that a similar thing happens when writing triggers, where you get `OLD` and `NEW` (depending on the kind of trigger you're writing).

Comment: Note that in the 2nd example it's better to use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` instead (although I understand that the OP probably doesn't want to do that).

Comment: I ran into this just now and typed a query into Google without much hope. I'm very happy to have landed on your answer. Thank you!